# Duplicate Tick Labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm searching for a way to extract all text elements from a matplotlibfigure including their position, style, alignment etc. Calling the `findobj(matplotlib.text.Text)` method of a figure does that job exactly. However, I get some weird duplicates for all the tick labels and I don't know how to handle them.

For example, use `findobj` for printing all Text elements of an axis:

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as p

p.plot([1,2,3])
p.xticks([1],["tick"])
ax = p.gca()
fig = p.gcf()

p.draw()
def print_texts(artist):
    for t in artist.findobj(matplotlib.text.Text):
        if t.get_visible() and t.get_text():
            print " %r @ %s" % (t.get_text(), t.get_position())

print "X-Axis Text Elements:"
print_texts(ax.xaxis)
print "Y-Axis Text Elements:"
print_texts(ax.yaxis)
```

Result:

```
X-Axis Text Elements:
 'tick' @ (1.0, 0.0)
 'tick' @ (0.0, 1.0)
Y-Axis Text Elements:
 u'1.0' @ (0.0, 1.0)
 u'1.0' @ (1.0, 0.0)
 u'1.5' @ (0.0, 1.5)
 u'1.5' @ (1.0, 0.0)
 u'2.0' @ (0.0, 2.0)
 u'2.0' @ (1.0, 0.0)
 u'2.5' @ (0.0, 2.5)
 u'2.5' @ (1.0, 0.0)
 u'3.0' @ (0.0, 3.0)
 u'3.0' @ (1.0, 0.0)
```

Note that all tick labels have duplicates positioned at the end of the axis. Why? How to filter them out from a list of Text elements? Their `get_visible()` attribute is True.

Another thing is that I first have to do call `draw()` in order to update/generate the ticks. How do I force an update of the tick labels? `matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar` seems to have a `update_ticks()` method, but I can't find something similar for ticks on the axes.

I also tried writing a custum backend and fetch all the texts from the `draw_text()`
method of the renderer. In contrast to the documentation `draw_text()` does
not receive a `matplotlib.text.Text` instance with all the necessary
information but only a simple string and a pre-layouted position.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, you'd probably have more luck with this on the mailing list.

Comment: I'm trying to write a backend for (xe)latex that separates figure and text elements like inkscape optionally does when saving to pdf. This way the texts' fonts will follow whatever font you use in your document without recreating the figure.

Comment: Oh, also posted on the mailing list using nabble but the messages took like 2-3 hours until they appeared on the list. This puzzled me to an extent and I opened the question here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was given in the matplotlib mailing list. The Tick object always creates two text labels, one for the left/bottom and one for the right/top. When a Tick artist is drawn its `label1On` and `label2On` attributes define which of the two child text labels receive the `draw()` call. Both of them remain in the visible state however.

So before iterating through all the text elements of a figure, I hide those labels that are not supposed to be seen:

```
for tick in fig.findobj(matplotlib.axis.Tick):
    tick.label1.set_visible(tick.label1On)
    tick.label2.set_visible(tick.label2On)

for text in fig.findobj(match=Text, include_self=False):
    s = text.get_text()
    if not s or not text.get_visible(): continue
    # do something with the texts
```